# Запуск сервера Gunicorn (PM2, systemd)

Tags: python, linux, gunicorn, systemd, pm2

В чем заключается разница запуска веб-приложения через связку *Gunicorn+PM2* и *Gunicorn+systemd*? Нигде не нашел прямого сравнения этих двух способов, тк слишком мало информации о Gunicorn как о менеджере процессов.

Comment: Ни в чём, как вам нравится, так и запускайте. Gunicorn это не менеджер процессов

Comment: Смотрите сравнение `PM2` и `systemd`, абстрагируйтесь от Gunicorn -- это WSGI сервер, и запустить его можно как угодно, в том числе через терминал